# MultiThreading with std::Vector in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, mutex

I want to create two threads accessing a vector concurrently, such that one keeps pushing elements at the back of the vector every 10 milliseconds, and another simply monitors the vector to see if its size has changed. Here, I get error "unlock of unowned mutex", can you please tell me why.

```
class SafeVec
{
public:
    SafeVec(){}
    ~SafeVec(){}
    void safePushBack(int val)
    {
        vecMutex.lock();
        vec.push_back(val);
        vecMutex.unlock();
    }
    size_t safeGetSize()
    {
        vecMutex.lock();
        size_t size = vec.size();
        vecMutex.unlock();
        return size;
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::mutex vecMutex;
};

class safeStream
{
public:
    safeStream(){}
    ~safeStream(){}
    void Test()
    {
        std::thread t(&safeStream::tMonitorVec, this); // spawned a new thread
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            myVec.safePushBack(1);
            Sleep(10);
        }
        stopMonitoringMutex.lock();
        stopMonitoring = true;
        stopMonitoringMutex.unlock();
    }

private:
    void tMonitorVec()
    {
        stopMonitoring = false;
        size_t tempSize = myVec.safeGetSize();
        int count = 0;
        stopMonitoringMutex.lock();
        while (1)
        {
            if (stopMonitoring)
            {
                stopMonitoringMutex.unlock();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                stopMonitoringMutex.unlock();
                if (tempSize != myVec.safeGetSize())
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << count;
    }
    SafeVec myVec;
    bool stopMonitoring;
    std::mutex stopMonitoringMutex;
};

int main()
{
    safeStream myStream;
    myStream.Test();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could this be because both threads acquire the vec of safeVec type simultaneously? But shouldnt the mutex inside safeVec take care of contention in this case.

Comment: Mutex is supposed to handle these cases (acquiring simultaneously by multiple threads) correctly, that's why it's for :)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you might want to read about e.g. [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard).

Comment: Use `std::lock_guard` instead of manually locking and unlocking the mutex. And if you make `stopMonitoring` an `atomic<bool>`, you won't need `stopMonitoringMutex`

Comment: Brava! You guys truly rock!

Comment: @Praetorian, how about making the vec also atomic<std::vector>, would this help? is it possible?

Comment: you can't `std::atomic<std::vector<T>>`, the type in `atomic` must be trivially copyable, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_trivially_copyable/

Comment: @PiotrS. I looked at lock guard, the impression I got is that it is helpful in case the critical section code throws exceptions, then the RAII will kick in, and make sure the mutex gets unlocked. Is that all, or am I missing something important?

Comment: @Spongetile: it wasn't me who suggested that, but yes, in case of multiple exit points (exceptions, branched returns), it guarantees the lock is released. Plase see also `std::unique_lock<T>`, this one has much more features

Comment: I see, thanks. Now I understand what Stroustrup meant by 'leaking locks'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens in your loop:

```
while (1)
{
    if (stopMonitoring)
    {
        stopMonitoringMutex.unlock();
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        // Whoops! I am here again !
        stopMonitoringMutex.unlock();
        if (tempSize != myVec.safeGetSize())
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

One more thing to consider: if you are using `std::mutex` only to protect concurrent access to field `bool stopMonitoring;` use `std::atomic<bool> stopMonitoring;` instead, and forget about mutexes.

Comment: Yes. Move `stopMonitoringMutex.lock();` inside `while`, because `stopMonitoringMutex.unlock();` is called in every `while` iteration.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Let me try again.